# SVM fail to predict

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

Here is my code:

```
int numPostivesrow = happy.rows;
int numNegativesrow = sad.rows;
int numrow = numPostivesrow + numNegativesrow;
int numcol = happy.cols;

Mat trainData(numrow, numcol, CV_32FC1); 
happy.copyTo(trainData.rowRange(0, numPostivesrow));
sad.copyTo(trainData.rowRange(numPostivesrow, numrow));

Mat labelsMat(numrow, 1, CV_32FC1);
labelsMat.rowRange(0, numPostivesrow).setTo(1.0);
labelsMat.rowRange(numPostivesrow, numrow).setTo(2.0);

CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = SVM::C_SVC;
params.C           = 0.1;
params.kernel_type = SVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit   = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, (int)1e7, 1e-6);

CvSVM svm;
svm.train(trainData, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

Mat testData(numPostivesrow, numcol, CV_32FC1);
testData = elbp;
testData.convertTo(testData ,CV_32FC1);

float response = svm.predict(testData);
```

The program can run until it comes to prediction.

Is there any problem with the params or the way I train my face LBP image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: svm.predict does only predict a *single* response, thus you need a *single* row in your testdata

Comment: @berak Is that means i need to reshape the train image and test image to 1d linear?

Comment: oh, if you haven't before, yes. definitely !